# GCM 401 Unauthorized error php

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Hi I am trying to use GCM for my android app.

Code is perfectly fine in my server. when i move to client server which is in godady server. It not working i checked with server and browser key but no luck i am getting 401 error. Is there any fire wall i need to disable in clients server tell me. Thanks in advance

Below is my php code

```
function sendPushNotificationToGCM($registatoin_ids, $message) {
    //Google cloud messaging GCM-API url
     $url        = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
    $fields     = array(
    'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
    'data' => $message,
);
// Google Cloud Messaging GCM API Key
define("GOOGLE_API_KEY", "my-api-key");
$headers = array(
    'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result == FALSE) {
    die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
}

<html>
<head>
<title>Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) Server in PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) Server in PHP</h1>
 <form method="post" action="index.php/?push=1">
 <div>
    <textarea rows="2" name="message" cols="23" placeholder="Message to transmit via GCM"></textarea>
</div>
<div><input type="submit"  value="Send Push Notification via GCM" /></div>
</form>
 <p><h3><?php echo $pushStatus; ?></h3></p>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Your code seems ok, pretty similar to the one I use and mine works. As per the GCM reference, it's an authentication error and there's a troubleshoot, see this: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html#auth_error

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the followng Key is correct:

```
// Google Cloud Messaging GCM API Key
define("GOOGLE_API_KEY", "my-api-key");
```

If you are using a Browser key you also need to make sure to autorize your site ip address for that key.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the IP set at the developer-console wasn't matching my server IP - you should recheck that besides of the API_KEY check mentioned in @meda's answer.

Note that, for testing purposes, the IP may be set as 0.0.0.0/0, which readily worked for me after replacing my server-IP & my server was also from godaddy.